# Adding a custom domain name (NOT a subdomain) to a static site hosted on Azure Storage

Tags: azure, dns, azure-storage

I have a domain registered through GoDaddy.

Currently there is an A record where:

- Host: @
- Points To: *IP Address*

This is pointing to a server that is currently serving the site.

I also have the site in an Azure Storage static web blob, and the endpoint is serving up the site and all is good.

I have tried registering a custom domain via the "asverify" method (see below), and Azure reports that it works.  **My custom domain "example.com" is accepted and all appears good** except, navigating to `https://example.com` never works (after disabling the A record above).

`Create a CNAME record with your DNS provider that points from the "asverify" subdomain (like asverify.www.contoso.com) to asverify.staticweb.blob.core.windows.net or asverify.staticweb.z5.web.core.windows.net. After this step completes, enter your domain below (exclude the 'asverify' subdomain). This method does not incur any downtime. To use this method, select the 'Use indirect CNAME validation' checkbox.`

I have done something similar previously with AppServices. I have another domain that I have added to an AppService that is not a subdomain (so it is `https://anotherexample.com` NOT `https://www.anotherexample.com`).  That was done with adding a TXT record to the DNS at GoDaddy, and works perfectly.

Does Azure Storage allow you to do this with a non-subdomain?  That is the only way that I want to access the site.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Azure Storage allow you to do this with a non-subdomain?

Unfortunately, Azure Storage does not allow you to use non-subdomains to perform this operation. **The subdomain is required, root domains are not supported.**

please see:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal#step-2-create-a-canonical-name-cname-record-with-your-domain-provider).

Answer (score 0):

While Azure Storage doesn't allow it as stated by the other anwser. You could very easily place an Azure CDN infront of it that does. To do this from the portal just go to the storage resource and search for the `Azure CDN` blade. From there you can create an endpoint to the storage or its static website. After creating the endpoint you can go to the resource and use the `Custom Domain` blade to set it up using a CNAME record.

Comment: I actually tried that.  I could get subdomains to work on the CDN, but not the root domain.  In GoDaddy DNS for example, I could enter a CNAME of cdnverify pointing to the endpoint and it would pick it up as cdnverify.example.com.  I could not seem to refer to the root domain though.  I tried '@' to no avail and 'example.com' also did not work.

Comment: @CodeWarrior are you sure that you used the `cdnverify` subdomain on both endpoints in the CNAME?